# How to use Carrierwave with the Volt framework?

Tags: file-upload, carrierwave, voltrb

It is pretty straightforward to use Carrierwave with Rails but not so much with Volt. I would like to know if it is possible to use CW with Volt, and what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely possible.  Volt is a rack app, and you can add other middleware (see the volt docs for help with that)  Sorry I can't be of more help, but my time is limited right now.  Anyone else want to give it a try?